# AndEngine Ease Founction

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

Can someone tell me how to implement ease function in this example:
I want to move mySprite to left/right with ease effect.

```
    public void offsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xOffsetStep,
        float yOffsetStep, int xPixelOffset, int yPixelOffset) {
    if(mCamera != null){
        mCamera.setCenter( (480 * xOffset )+300, mCamera.getCenterY() );

    }

    mySprite.addShapeModifier(new MoveModifier(3,mySprite.getX(),?????????,mySprite.getY(),mySprite.getY(),EaseBackOut.getInstance()));
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First of all, update your AndEngine version. There are no `ShapeModifier`s anymore, they are called `EntityModifier`s, and the method `addShapeModifier` doesn't exist. There is a method `Camera.offsetCenter(..)` so you don't need to do it on your own.

Anyways, when kind of EaseFunction do you want? There are many, and you use it this way (With the most updated `MoveModifier` class):

```
mySprite.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(duration, fromX, toX, fromY, toY, easeFunction);
```

You should run the [EaseFunctionExample](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/EaseFunctionExample.java) on your device/emulator, and decide which one you want.

If you want to move `mySprite` on the X axis, you could do:

```
mySprite.registerEntityModifier(new MoveXModifier(duration, mySprite.getX(), toX, easeFunction);
```